# Could distinct JOIN types give the same result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE sitters (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  user_id UUID REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  headline VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  user_id UUID REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  sitter_id UUID REFERENCES sitters,
  start_date date NOT NULL,
  end_date date NOT NULL,
  pets_ids UUID[] NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'created',
  total_amount_cents INT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  booking_id UUID REFERENCES bookings ON DELETE CASCADE,
  sender_id UUID REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  receiver_id UUID REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  seen_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

So:

- A user can be a sitter.
- A booking has a user and a sitter.
- A message belongs to a unique booking.

I'd like to:

Given a `user_id`, a `sitter_id` and a `booking_id` return booking's messages if:

- `booking_id` is valid
- That booking id matches the given `user_id`, `sitter_id` or both.

So I got:

```
SELECT m.*,
b.user_id, b.sitter_id
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN messages m
ON m.booking_id=b.id
WHERE b.id=$1 AND (b.user_id=$2 OR b.sitter_id=$3);
```

I'd like to receive:

- nothing if booking does not exist
- nothing is none of `user_id` or `sitter_id` matches
- booking id fields if booking exists but has not messages

And it works properly, but after trying distinct JOINS I see same results. Any scenarios where it could break?

Comment: Your query seems to do what you want it to do.  An inner join would fail the third bullet point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by:

> And it works properly, but after trying distinct JOINS I see same results. Any scenarios where it could break?

It seems that you're using the word "distinct" in the English sense, not in the SQL sense, which is a bit confusing in an SQL question.

What are you joining on?

- Any left joins to the other tables should have no effect, with the possible exception of your pets table.
- Joining to the users or sitters table could potentially cause the query to not work if the user/sitter is not found.

> I'd like to recieve booking id fields if booking exists but has not messages

The way that you're selecting columns will cause a null booking id, if there are no messages for the booking.

- consider listing all columns manually

Please see my simplified SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b976/2
Please, also consider clarifying your question.